Jittering in time-interleaved ADCs
I am doing some research on Time-interleaved Analog-to-Digital Converters impairments modeling and I am trying to figuring out which physical phenomenon I am witnessing (I am not an engineer, so my intuition is unfortunately poor).
So basically I have data from a 4-channels Ti ADC that looks like this (the picture comes from another thread I opened here on SE a while ago):

When there is no input - so when $x(t)$ is only noise - I could model the output at each sub-ADC as an autoregressive process of order $1$. The issue is that I do not understand why. Someone I work with suggested that it might be the sampling jittering, but could that be?
Suppose the stimulus is now a CW, i.e. $x(t) = e^{2 \pi i f_0 t}$; if I understand correctly, sampling jittering means that the sampler samples $x(nT + \xi_n)$, $n \ge 0$ instead of at exactly $nT$. The Wikipedia page says that $\xi_n$ could be normally distributed. So $$x(nT + \xi_n) = e^{2 \pi i f_0 (nT + \xi_n)} \approx x(nT) + i x(nT) \xi_n =(1 + i \xi_n) x(nT) $$ so the effect of this random jitter on a complex wave seems to be multiplicative noise; and if $\xi_n$ are uncorrelated, I do not see how the spectrum of $ (1 + i \xi_n) x(nT) $ shall contain the AR(1) components.
Even worse if I consider $x(t) = w(t)$ (white noise process), I would expect to see white spectrum at the output even with random jittering, or? Does the Ti structure play a role here? Or is the jittering that behaves like an AR(1), could that be? I am confused :/
Thank you!

Jitter is typically specified as an rms quantity. I prefer to review the effects of jitter in the frequency domain where it is given as a power spectral density, such as the one-sided power spectral density due to phase fluctuations $\mathscr{L}_\phi(f)$ which you find on most oscillator and frequency source datasheets as "Phase Noise". If you properly integrate phase noise and take the square root, you get the single rms quantity of jitter (where "properly" means multiply by two to get the two-sided quantity and choose the right start and end frequency offsets based on application).
Further phase noise that is on the sampling clock will be transferred to the signal being sampled via a convolution process (multiplication in time is convolution in frequency), such that if a single tone was sampled, the phase noise induced on that tone would be the same level in dBc/Hz as it was on the sampling clock itself (dBc/Hz meaning dB below the carrier, in power per Hz as as a power spectral density).
What is significant about the frequency domain result is that we see there are regions (frequency offsets) where the phase noise is not a white noise process, but going up in power as the offset frequency goes down. The rate of phase noise power increasing as frequency decreases will go up as frequency goes down, meaning starting from a high frequency offset there will be a region of white noise where the power is flat, transitioning to pink noise as $1/f$ where the power is increasing 10 dB/decade, transitioning to red or Brownian noise as $1/f^2$ increasing 20 dB/decade which is consistent with a random walk process (what you would get if you integrated or accumulated white noise). The offset frequency corresponds to the reciprocal of the observation time (consider how we would need to observe a process for an infinite amount of time to truly observe DC!).  So how long the output of each ADC is observed and the nature of the phase noise on the sampling clock will effect the nature of the noise in the sampled signal itself.
The graphic below demonstrates an example power spectral density due to phase fluctuations (phase noise) and it's individual components.


Thank you for your time. From your answer I deduce that yes, jitter can be responsible for the $1/f$ behavior that I observed in my data. However one question remain: your analysis is done in frequency domain, but is there a standard/textbook way to model (my) $\xi_n$ so that the ADC output has the desired spectral properties?

What for you mean my “desired”? Are you asking how to model 1/f noise in the time domain or something else?

(if so, that would be great to post as a separate question as the answer is too valuable to be buried in the comments to this other question)
